# Building spatialindex in Postgres with JNDI for GeoNetwork?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index, tomcat, geonetwork

Which steps should be taken to build the spatialindex table inside PostgreSQL when using a JNDI connection?

Is the table built by GeoNetwork or does it need to be created manually?

---

What I have tried so far:

For building the `spatialindex` table in GeoNetwork (3.0.6) in the Postgres database as opposed to using a shapefile internally, I switched database connection to JNDI, as recommended in the [advanced configuration docs](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/advanced-configuration/#advanced-configuration-for-larger-catalogs).

**Creating JNDI connection first**

To do so, I had to change the database type used in `srv.xml` to `<import resource="../config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml"/>` and configure my datasource in `context.xml` like so:

```
<Resource 
        name="jdbc/geonetwork"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/geonetwork" 
        username="geonetwork_user" 
        password="" 
        maxActive="20" 
        maxIdle="20" 
        maxWait="200"
        initialSize="20"
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="120" 
        logAbandoned="true" 
        testOnBorrow="true" 
        defaultReadOnly="false" 
        defaultAutoCommit="false" 
        validationQuery="SELECT 1" 
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="1800000" 
        testWhileIdle="true" 
        numTestsPerEvictionRun="3" 
        poolPreparedStatements="true" 
        maxOpenPreparedStatements="1200" 
        provideDataStore="true"  --> tried this to build spatialindex table
/>
```

I added the `provideDataStore` parameter according to this [section](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/advanced-configuration/#database-connection-pool-managed-by-the-container). Actually it looks like it must go into the `/config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml` file, but this is rejected by the application.

I adapted some configuration in the `/config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml` file as mentioned [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GeoNetwork-3-0-Postgis-JNDI-setup-td5247772.html):

```
 <bean id="jdbcDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/geonetwork"/>
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="exposeAccessContext" value="false"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="jpaVendorAdapterDatabaseParam" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="POSTGRESQL"/>
 </bean>
```

With this configuration, I was able to switch the database connection to JNDI.

**Build spatialindex into Postgres**

But nevertheless, it does not build the spatialindex into Postgres.

I tried:

- Restarting tomcat
- Harvesting new datasets
- Playing around with the `provideDataStore` parameter
- Creating the table `spatialindex` myself to make GeoNetwork use it on restart

The table is defined according to the definition from the [2.10 branch's create-db-postgis.sql](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/2.10.x/web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/setup/sql/create/create-db-postgis.sql) file:

```
CREATE TABLE spatialindex
 (
    fid int not null,
    id  varchar(250),
    primary key(fid)
  );
CREATE INDEX spatialindexNDX1 ON spatialindex(id);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('spatialindex', 'the_geom', 4326, 'MULTIPOLYGON', 2 );
CREATE INDEX spatialindexNDX2 on spatialindex USING GIST(the_geom);
```

But my `spatialindex.shp` file in the data directory still gets altered instead of the database table.

Is there anything else neccessary to make GeoNetwork build the `spatialindex` table in Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I figured out how to make GeoNetwork create the spatialindex table in PostGIS (**not using JNDI**).
This approach is taken from [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-use-PostGIS-spatial-index-in-3-0-0-Urgent-td5208696.html).

- In srv.xml choose postgres.xml as database configuration
- Configure postgres.xml to contain this:

> ```
> <import resource="defaultJdbcDataSource.xml" />
> <import resource="postgis-alternate-datasource.xml" />
>
> <bean id="jpaVendorAdapterDatabaseParam" class="java.lang.String">
>     <constructor-arg value="POSTGRESQL"/>
> </bean>
>
> <bean id="jdbcDriverClassName" class="java.lang.String">
>     <constructor-arg value="org.postgis.DriverWrapper"/>
> </bean>
>
> <bean id="jdbcURL" class="java.lang.String">
>     <constructor-arg value="jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://${jdbc.host}:${jdbc.port}/${jdbc.database}"/>
> </bean>
> ```

- Configure jdbc.properties accordingly.

On next GeoNetwork restart, it will automatically create the spatialindex table. Then, I triggered a new indexing from the admin interface to populate the table.

However, this approach is not optimal from my perspective as it is said to be deprecated in the [2.10 docs](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/advanced-configuration/#managing-the-database-connection-pool-through-apache-dbcp) already and wants the database configuration inside the application files, as opposite to the JNDI configuration.

Comment: What the docs said that it is deprecated is the JNDI approach.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't figure out how to do it with JNDI, but wanted to document my current approach. First, here is the approach with JNDI, which does not lead to success in the current Geonetwork versions 3.6 and 3.7.

## JNDI (no success)

Ensure you have a JNDI resource configuration in the Tomcat servlet container connecting to your Postgres/Postgis database:

`docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
...
        echo '
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/geonetwork"
   auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   username="'${POSTGRES_DB_USERNAME}'"
   password="'${POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD}'"
   factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
   driverClassName="org.postgis.DriverWrapper"
   url="jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://'${POSTGRES_DB_HOST}':5432/'${db_gn}'"
   maxActive="66"
   maxIdle="12"
   minIdle="12"
   removeAbandoned="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="3600"
   logAbandoned="true"
   testOnBorrow="true"
   defaultAutoCommit="false"
   validationQuery="SELECT 1"
   defaultTransactionIsolation="2"
   accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true"
   poolPreparedStatements="true"
   maxOpenPreparedStatements="1200"
  />
</Context>' > "${CATALINA_HOME}"/conf/context.xml
...
```

Comment out the default database configuration and enable the pre-built JNDI database configuration:

```
sed -i -e 's|<import resource="../config-db/h2.xml"/>|<!--<import resource="../config-db/h2.xml"/> -->|g' ./geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml
sed -i -e 's|<!--<import resource="../config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml"/> -->|<import resource="../config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml"/>|g' ./geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml
```

If Tomcat boots normally with Geonetwork, JNDI (which uses JDBC) will run.

Now the question posed by the questioner is where to set the parameter provideDataStore to true so that Geonetwork no longer uses the shapefile to store spatial information (bounding boxes etc.) I have not made the following approach (which works under Geonetwork 2.10.4) work.

`docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
        # Not working 1 (no effect):
        sed -i -e 's|</default>|</default>\
  <resources>\
    <resource enabled="true">\
      <name>main-db</name>\
      <provider>jeeves.resources.dbms.JNDIPool</provider>\
      <config>\
        <context>java:/comp/env</context>\
        <resourceName>jdbc/geonetwork</resourceName>\
        <url>jdbc:postgresql_postGIS://'${POSTGRES_DB_HOST}':5432/'${db_gn}'</url>\
        <provideDataStore>true</provideDataStore>\
      </config>\
    </resource>\
  </resources>|' "${CATALINA_HOME}"/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config.xml

        # Not working 2 (error):
#       sed -i -e 's|<property name="exposeAccessContext" value="false"/>|<property name="exposeAccessContext" value="false"/>\
#  <property name="provideDataStore" value="true"/>|' "${CATALINA_HOME}"/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml
```

## JDBC only (works out-of-the-box)

Comment out the default database configuration and enable the pre-built JDBC database configuration:

```
sed -i -e 's|<import resource="../config-db/h2.xml"/>|<!--<import resource="../config-db/h2.xml"/> -->|g' ./geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml
sed -i -e 's|<!--<import resource="../config-db/postgres-postgis.xml"/> -->|<import resource="../config-db/postgres-postgis.xml"/>|g' ./geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml
```

`jdbc.properties` (increased `maxActive` and increased `maxOpenPreparedStatements`)

```
jdbc.basic.removeAbandoned=true
jdbc.basic.removeAbandonedTimeout=120
jdbc.basic.logAbandoned=true
jdbc.basic.maxActive=64
jdbc.basic.maxIdle=${jdbc.basic.maxActive}
jdbc.basic.initialSize=${jdbc.basic.maxActive}
jdbc.basic.maxWait=200
jdbc.basic.testOnBorrow=true
jdbc.basic.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=10000
jdbc.basic.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
jdbc.basic.testWhileIdle=true
jdbc.basic.numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
jdbc.basic.poolPreparedStatements=true
jdbc.basic.maxOpenPreparedStatements=1200
jdbc.basic.validationQuery=SELECT 1
jdbc.basic.defaultReadOnly=false
jdbc.basic.defaultAutoCommit=false
```

Use standard `docker-entrypoint.sh` (needs Docker) via https://github.com/geonetwork/docker-geonetwork and maybe see my pull request.

After starting, a table called spatialindex should appear in the geonetwork database. Via harvesting or via the settings tools, the index can be regenerated and the table should be filled.